# "Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused" error when trying to get two Azure VMs to communicate on different ports

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have two Azure VMs I set up to test a program I made. The program is to be run on both VMs, where synchronous operations are performed, requiring the VMs to communicate with eachother on different ports using TCP protocols. To access my Azure VMs, I SSH'd into them on port 22 using Putty on my local machine. The VMs are on the same subnet, and I am trying to get them to communicate with eachother via their public IP. I have set up both VMs inbound rules to accept messages from eachother on any port, using any protocol [here is an example of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzZaM.jpg).

During the execution of my program, I encounter the following error "Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused". After this, I did some investigating. First, I had both VMs ping eachother, which they successfully did. Then, on both VMs, I ran the command "telnet other.ip 22", where other.ip is the other VMs public IP. This seems to work, as seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No1f5.png). When I run "telnet other.ip 6000", or any other port besides 22 for that matter, I get the same error of "Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused". My rational is that if I can get the "telnet" command running on any port, that my program will likely work too.

I am not too sure what my issue could be at this point, and my internet searches have not helped me. I doubt there is an issue of a port being backlogged with communication requests given my current inbound rules. Also, I did try to change my inbound rules so that my VMs would receive messages on any port, using any protocol, from *any* source, which resulted in the same error (I then changed it back from 'any source' to only my other VMs public IP for security purposes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you may check two points:

- If there is any firewall inside the VM that is blocking the connection from the external network with port 6000. For example, if you are using Ubuntu VM, you can refer to [How to Set Up a Firewall with UFW on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-firewall-on-ubuntu-18-04/). Then disable the firewall with the command `sudo ufw disable` or add a firewall rule to verify this.
- Run the command on Linux to see open ports. `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`. You should see port 6000 in the output. If not, it might mean that your program is not started well.

Let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I just checked, and my firewall is in fact inactive. When I run the command "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN", 6000 is not listed, and this may be the root of my problem. In fact, there are only two ports actively listening to anything, 22 and 53. I actually thought that changing my inbound rules to accept all incoming messages from all ports would tell my OS to listen on all ports and accept messages from other.ip, but I see now that I may be mistaken. I still find this strange though, are you aware of what the inbound rules are actually meant for?

Comment: if the port is not listening，it means your program is not waiting for a connection. Do you sure it can work locally？The inbound rules should not related to this.

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation, I have actually just determined that my program does in fact correctly listen on port 6000, but I still get the same error. At this point, I feel as if it has to be a silly error I made in my program elsewhere, and not an issue with the way I am using my VMs, so I will investigate this more closely. Thank you very much again for your time

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall rules. If your organization tent to use firewall then add port 6000 in inbound and outbound chain.

you can connect the remote host with port number only when it is in listening state.

sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I checked my firewall and it is in fact disabled, so I don't think that is the issue. I used the command "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN" and as it turns out, port 6000 is not listening. I thought that changing my inbound rules to allow traffic to all ports from other.ip would tell my OS to listen on all ports, but I appear to be incorrect in this thinking.